# dynamic regex in R

Tags: regex, r

The below code works so long as `before` and `after` strings have no characters that are special to a regex:

```
before <- 'Name of your Manager (note "self" if you are the Manager)' #parentheses cause problem in regex
after  <- 'CURRENT FOCUS'

pattern <- paste0(c('(?<=', before, ').*?(?=', after, ')'), collapse='')
ex <- regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl=TRUE))
```

Does R have a function to escape strings to be used in regexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\Q...\E` to surround the verbatim subpatterns:

```
# test data
before <- "A."
after <- ".Z"
x <- c("A.xyz.Z", "ABxyzYZ")

pattern <- sprintf('(?<=\\Q%s\\E).*?(?=\\Q%s\\E)', before, after)
```

which gives:

```
> gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = TRUE) > 0
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: even better! I wasn't aware of `\Q...\E`. I can see it coming in handy in many places.

Comment: This is very handy! If you don't need `perl = TRUE` for your regex, it is not a requirement for `\Q...\E` to work.

Answer (score 7):

In Perl, there is http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html for doing exactly that. If the doc is correct when it says

> > Returns the value of EXPR with all the ASCII non-"word" characters backslashed. (That is, all ASCII characters not matching /[A-Za-z_0-9]/ will be preceded by a backslash in the returned string, regardless of any locale settings.)

then you can achieve the same by doing:

```
quotemeta <- function(x) gsub("([^A-Za-z_0-9])", "\\\\\\1", x)
```

And your pattern should be:

```
pattern <- paste0(c('(?<=', quotemeta(before), ').*?(?=', quotemeta(after), ')'),
                  collapse='')
```

Quick sanity check:

```
a <- "he'l(lo)"
grepl(a, a)
# [1] FALSE
grepl(quotemeta(a), a)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: perfect! I suppose it isn't a core function because R isn't usually meant for text processing.

Answer (score 1):

dnagirl, such a function exists and is `glob2rx`

```
a <- "he'l(lo)"
tt <- glob2rx(a)
# [1] "^he'l\\(lo)$"

before <- 'Name of your Manager (note "self" if you are the Manager)'
tt <- glob2rx(before)
# [1] "^Name of your Manager \\(note \"self\" if you are the Manager)$"
```

You can just remove the "^" and "$" from the strings by doing:

```
substr(tt, 2, nchar(tt)-1)
# [1] "he'l\\(lo)"
```

Comment: I saw `glob2rx` before I posted my answer. I don't think it is the function for the task, try things like `glob2rx(".*")` for example.

Comment: @flodel, I'm aware of its limitations. Most of the time it worked for me. The only reason I posted here is because of [**this Ricardo's post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224620/r-strings-to-regex-appropriate-strings#16224620) where it seems that his question is an exact duplicate of this one.. and I was asked to post my comment here as an answer.