# Rownames with parentheses: are they allowed in R?

Tags: regex, r, names

I am trying to subset data, using names of work and test set

```
ws_data <- subset(data, grepl(paste0("v*[0-9]_",ws_names, collapse="|" ),
           rownames(data))==TRUE)
```

It seems to work ok, but for the rownames like

```
"(Difluoromethoxy)trifluoromethane"
```

are just skipped.
Are parenthese allowed as legal names in R? How can I solve this problem not changing row names?
Thanks in advance!

***The example of data***

64   |   v0064_(Chloro)(trifluor)omethane | -51.5   | 510.9 | 104.5 |   11.2 |
65 | v0067_(Dichloro)difluoromethane | -81.0    | 233.0 |   121.0 | 16.1 |

***Regular expressions***

> rownames(ts)[1]
>      [1] "Bromotrifluoromethane"
>
> rownames(data)[1]
>      [1] "v0001_Bromotrifluoromethane"
>
> grepl("v[0-9]*_Bromotrifluoromethane", rownames(data)[1])
>      [1] TRUE
>
> grepl("v*[0-9]_Bromotrifluoromethane", rownames(data)[1])
>      [1] TRUE

Comment: Can you post a subset of your data that shows the problem?

Comment: Data frame is quite massive, but I added the short example

Comment: Wait, so is the column starting `"v0064_(Chloro)(trifluor)omethane"` an actual column of data, or the row names of your dataset? It looks like your row names are numbers, 64 and 65 in this case.

Comment: No, they are the rownames. I think, it is just the way RStudio depicts the data in the View window. I will fix the example if it's necessary

Comment: Your pattern says to match 0 or more "v"s followed by a single digit, followed by an underscore "_", followed by the element of ws_names.  That pattern does not match anything in the example data.  I think you may want the "*" after "[0-9]", i.e. "v[0-9]*_" instead of what you have now.

Comment: the first one doesn't match because you have a capital "V", and the second one matches because it matches "1_Bromo..." (the match is not from the front - if you want to enforce that, add a "^")

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now I get it.

Comment: Thanks for the help with regular expressions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem you're facing is the fact that the parentheses have a meaning in regular expressions. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221899/dynamic-regex-in-r) has a cure for that, which you can use to do something like this:

```
quotemeta <- function(x) gsub("([^A-Za-z_0-9])", "\\\\\\1", x)

data[grepl(paste0("^v[0-9]*_", quotemeta(ws_names), collapse="|"), rownames(data)), ]
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I was thinking about something like that, but it is much more neater.

Answer (score 2):

In general you can have rownames with characters like that in names and rownames, you just need to quote them when using them.  I think the problem here is the `subset` function, it allows some unusual ways to specify the subset which makes some things easier, but others harder.  It is trying to figure out what you mean by the rownames (rather than just take them as literal strings) and the parentheses are probably confusing that process.

Try something like:

```
data[ grepl( paste0("v*[0-9]_",ws_names, collapse="|" ), rownames(data)), ]
```

You may also be able to simplify this using `%in%` if you can construct the list of names.

Also see `fortune(69)`, the ==TRUE is redundant and slightly less useful than adding 0 or multiplying by 1.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it seems to give the same result as previous code. And, may I ask what is **fortune(69)**?

Comment: @Boddha, the fortunes package contains collected wit and wisdom from the R community.  If you install and load the package and then run `fortune(69)` it will print that specific fortune, running `fortune()` will choose a random fortune.  Reading a few random fortunes every now and then can be entertaining and/or educational.

Comment: Oh, that's great! I will surely try it.