# regex in R - combining two patterns in "OR" fashion. Can't spot the error.

Tags: regex, r

I want to find `pat1` OR `pat2` in `vec`

```
vec <- c("(and) i.e.", "(and) ie", "(and)ie", "and i.e.", "and ie", "and) i.e.")

pat1 <- "\\(and) i\\.e\\."
pat2 <- "\\(and) ie"
```

I attempt to combine the two patterns using `(pat1|pat2)`

```
# combine the two patterns 
pat1or2 <- paste0("(", pat1, "|", pat2, ")")
# [1] "(\\(and) i\\.e\\.|\\(and) ie)"

grep(pat1, vec, value=TRUE)
# [1] "(and) i.e."

grep(pat2, vec, value=TRUE)
# [1] "(and) ie"

grep(pat1or2, vec, value=TRUE)
# character(0)
```

Clearly, I am missing something and I cannot spot it.
(Tried messing with perl and fixed, but that wasnt it)

Can you point out my error in combining the two patterns?

Comment: you don't necessarily need to escape `)` normally. Here you shouldn't have the first and last parenthesis, but if you want to, then you'll have to escape as in flodel's answer. That's if you try, `pat1or2 <- paste0(pat1, "|", pat2)`, it'll work.

Comment: Thanks Arun.  I was under the impression that if I was using a pipe then I had to wrap in parens.  From what you are saying, it seems this is not the case?

Comment: Ridardo, yes. Try the pattern from that comment.

Comment: The obvious follow up question is:  When _are_ parens required?

Comment: Unless you need to capture a pattern for ex: `gsub("^bla(.*?)bla", "\\1", x)` where `x` is, say, `c("blablebla", "bleblable")`, I don't see a reason to cover multiple patterns or any regexp in parenthesis.

Comment: parens without backslash are for capturing which I agree you don't need here. But if you want to match parens (your case here), then you need to backslash them (or use `fixed = TRUE`) otherwise they will have a completely different meaning: the "capture" meaning. Finally, having unbalanced unslashed parens is wrong and you are lucky (or unlucky I might say) R did not complain.

Comment: I would have preferred the complaint ;)   Thanks again for the help and clarifications

Comment: I prefer to put literal parens and dots in character classes rather than after backslashes, due to occasional problems with multiple evaluations.  So `"\."` (`"\\."` in R) would be `"[.]"` and `"\("` would be `"[(]"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to backslash all of your parentheses. Your two patterns should be:

```
pat1 <- "\\(and\\) i\\.e\\."
pat2 <- "\\(and\\) ie"
```

After that, everything should be fine, with or without `perl = TRUE`. What could have put you on track to finding the error is using `perl = TRUE` with your old (wrong) patterns:

```
grep(pat1, vec, value=TRUE, perl = TRUE)
# Error in grep(pat1, vec, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE) : 
#   invalid regular expression '\(and) i\.e\.'
```

making it clear you had unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: doh!  thanks @flodel!   Interestingly, I used `glob2rx` to escape my original strings.  I wonder why it escapes opening parens but not closing

Comment: Ricardo, You don't need to escape the `)`. But you add a `(` and `)` at the beginning and the end, which makes it essential to escape the ones in-between. Check my comment under your question.

Comment: @Ricardo, you might find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221899/dynamic-regex-in-r

Answer (score 2):

It can be simplified a bit like this:

```
pat1 <- "(and) i.e."
pat2 <- "(and) ie"

ok <- grepl(pat1, vec, fixed = TRUE) | grepl(pat2, vec, fixed = TRUE)  
vec[ ok ]
```

This could alternately be written in this form which generalizes to more than two patterns:

```
pats <- c(pat1, pat2)
ok <- Reduce(function(x, y) x | grepl(y, vec, fixed = TRUE), pats, FALSE)
vec[ ok ]
```

Comment: Thanks Gabor. In reality I have several dozen patterns and a vector of about 5e7 to search through and in fact substitute (all with the same replacement). Thus my intention is to minimize the amount of calls to `sub`