# R use variable within regex

Tags: regex, r

Okay - maybe this is a better example.  I am looking for guidance/references on how to reference a variable within a regex - not how to build a regex for this data.

How can you use a value from a variable to regex the next variable?

```
library(plyr)    
library(tm)
library(stringr)
library(gsubfn)
```

Dataset of velocities

```
d1$sub <- c("LEFT CAROTID STENOSIS: (50-69)APPROXIMATELY 50-55% (0-49)LESS THAN 50%     COMMON:", "LEFT CAROTID STENOSIS: (50-69)APPROXIMATELY 60-70% (0-49)LESS THAN 50% COMMON:", "LEFT CAROTID STENOSIS: (40-60)APPROXIMATELY 40% INCOMPLETE SCAN SEE NOTES (40-50)LESS THAN 50% COMMON:")

d1$sub
[1] "LEFT CAROTID STENOSIS: (50-69)APPROXIMATELY 50-55% (0-49)LESS THAN 50% COMMON:"                        
[2] "LEFT CAROTID STENOSIS: (50-69)APPROXIMATELY 60-70% (0-49)LESS THAN 50% COMMON:"                        
[3] "LEFT CAROTID STENOSIS: (40-60)APPROXIMATELY 40% INCOMPLETE SCAN SEE NOTES (40-    50)LESS THAN 50% COMMON:"
```

extract sub1

```
d1$sub1 <- as.character(lapply((strapply(d1$sub,"((?<=LEFT CAROTID STENOSIS:).{5,}?(?=(\\(|COMMON)))", perl=TRUE)), unique))
d1$sub1
[1] " (50-69)APPROXIMATELY 50-55% "                       
[2] " (50-69)APPROXIMATELY 60-70% "                       
[3] " (40-60)APPROXIMATELY 40% INCOMPLETE SCAN SEE NOTES "
```

Now reference sub1 to get sub2 from the data

Want to return "(0-49)LESS THAN 50%", "(0-49)LESS THAN 50%", And "(40-50)LESS THAN 50%"

```
d1$sub2 <- as.character(lapply((strapply(d1$sub,"((?<=\\d1$sub1).*?(?=COMMON))", perl=TRUE)), unique))
d1$sub2
[1] "NULL" "NULL" "NULL"
```

*** Original Post Below ****

I am extracting medical information from text reports, and am attempting to use one variable ($sub1) as part of a regex to find the next variable ($sub2).

How can you use a value from a variable to regex the next variable?

```
library(plyr)
library(tm)
library(stringr)
library(gsubfn)

#Dataset of velocities
d1 <- c("CCA: 135 cm/sec ICA: 50 cm/sec", "CCA: 150 cm/sec ICA: 75 cm/sec")
d1
[1] "CCA: 135 cm/sec ICA: 50 cm/sec" "CCA: 150 cm/sec ICA: 75 cm/sec"

#Lookahead to get sub1
d1$sub1 <- as.character(lapply((strapply(d1,"(.*?(?=ICA:))", perl=TRUE)), unique))
Warning message:
In d1$sub1 <- as.character(lapply((strapply(d1, "(.*?(?=ICA:))",  :
 Coercing LHS to a list
d1
[[1]]
[1] "CCA: 135 cm/sec ICA: 50 cm/sec"

[[2]]
[1] "CCA: 150 cm/sec ICA: 75 cm/sec"

$sub1
[1] "CCA: 135 cm/sec " "CCA: 150 cm/sec "

#Now reference sub1 to get sub2 - does not work?
#Want to return "ICA:50 cm/sec" and "ICA:75 cm/sec"
#Used paste(d1$sub1) to try getting the $sub1 variable into the regex, but doesn't work)
d1$sub2 <- as.character(lapply((strapply(d1,"((?<=paste(d1$sub1)).*?)", perl=TRUE)), unique))
d1$sub2
[1] "NULL" "NULL" "NULL"
```

The text has structure, but is very variable in terms of length, content, etc.  Defining the first variable ($sub1) is easy, but using it to define the second variable will be the most precise.

Maybe I should have emphasized that the text is very variable - so a simple regex based on the text pattern will not work.  I need to use the first variable to locate the second within the text.  It is medical information so I can't post actual data.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question - the desired final output is 2 variables ($sub1 = CA: 135 cm/sec, $sub2 =CCA: 50cm/sec).  I can generate the variables but am struggling with how to reference the first to get a locator for the second.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the `paste0()` function. That will put together all your variables and any regular expressions you want to use.

```
grep(paste0("^.*", variable, ".*$"), d1)
```

you can also add the argument `collapse = ""` to `paste0()` if your variable could have >1 element

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
> d1 <- c("CCA: 135 cm/sec ICA: 50 cm/sec", "CCA: 150 cm/sec ICA: 75 cm/sec")
> t(strapplyc(d1, "\\w+: \\S+ \\S+", simplify = TRUE))
     [,1]              [,2]            
[1,] "CCA: 135 cm/sec" "ICA: 50 cm/sec"
[2,] "CCA: 150 cm/sec" "ICA: 75 cm/sec"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll [need to escape various characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16222490/817778) to use variables in regex, but why not do the simpler thing?

```
sub('(.*)ICA.*', '\\1', d1)
#[1] "CCA: 135 cm/sec " "CCA: 150 cm/sec "
sub('.*(ICA.*)', '\\1', d1)
#[1] "ICA: 50 cm/sec" "ICA: 75 cm/sec"
```